# Analytic solution to recursive functions

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Let's say we have a function $$ F( n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} ) $$ where

$$ F(1) = \mathrm{const.} $$
$$ F( n \geq 2 ) = C\frac{ F(n-1) + a }{ F(n-1) + b } $$

Where C, a and b are constants. Is there a clear-cut process to go about finding a generic solution to F(n)?

I realize that being a constant F(1) can be rewritten as $$ F(1) = C\frac{ A + a }{ A + b } $$ but it doesn't help much.

Edit: please note that the function F appears in both the numerator and the denominator.

I have tried rewriting F as
$$ F(n) = C F_1(n) F_2(n) $$
$$ F_1(n) = F(n-1) + a  $$
$$ F_2(n) = \frac{1}{ F(n-1) + b } $$

But again it doesn't help, because upon expansion of those functions F(n) appears again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving nonlinear recursive relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403405/solving-nonlinear-recursive-relation)

Comment: The example only has the function in the denominator, so it can be easily simplified, whereas in this instance the function F appears in both the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: The answers in that duplicate (out of [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=homographic+sequence)) give methods (and links) to get a closed form for a general [*homographic sequence*](https://www.google.com/search?q=homographic+sequence).

Comment: People are not supposed to read the comments to understand what you mean by "The example" in your edit. Moreover, my previous comment answers that objection.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at the links and will update the question accordingly.

Comment: This question seems quite similar, however it doesn't have an answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272535/closed-form-of-sequences-defined-recursively-by-a-homographic-function